# Fonts appear different when migrated from Windows XP to Windows 7?

Tags: fonts

I’m a graphic designer and just upgraded my work computer from Windows XP to Windows 7, I added all the fonts I had on my old setup—including erasing the stock ones and using the fonts from old system just in case their a little different—and I’m noticing that they look slightly different.

Is there any way to make them look like the original fonts?

I doubt there is any way to fix it but there’s no harm in asking.

Comment: I deleted all the ones that were not protected, certannly did not replace the system like ones, as the new font method is entirely different with layers of fonts inc languages in each file item. Tossed in my own collection which is simple single layer english only, and did not see any variations in rendering my original collection.  Please explain what your seeing, show a picture if you have one. (valid pictures can be edited in by users with more rep)

Answer (score 1):

You could try [diabling ClearType](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-font-smoothing-windows) on your Windows 7 machine, which disables font smoothing, which probably was disabled on your older operating system.